# Debugging UDK using nFringe in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio-2005, unreal-development-kit, unrealscript

This is a pretty niche question, so I am not expecting a huge response...

Basically, I am learning how to use the UDK by following some tutorials, namely this one:

http://forums.epicgames.com/showthread.php?p=27043379#post27043379

So far everything is going pretty well. The only real hangup I've had is getting everything to work in Visual Studio 2005 using this nFringe plugin. For a long time, couldn't get them to work at all. I've gotten into two or three chapters of the tutorial, and I've managed to use Visual Studio to edit the code, but I can't build the scripts within VS; I have to go to UDK Frontend to do that. And worse still, I can only really use Log commands in the unrealscripts to debug anything.

So my question is this: is it even possible to configure these tools in a way that I can put breakpoints in VS and have them be caught when I test the game? I feel as though I don't have something setup correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I havnt tried using breakpoints yet but I know its possable to build with nfringe and visual studio . You need to add a line to the

```
udk game / config / udk engine .ini
```

search for

editpackages

exactly like that , then youll see a block like this

> EditPackagesInPath=....\Development\Src
>   EditPackages=Core
>   EditPackages=Engine
>   EditPackages=GFxUI
>   EditPackages=GameFramework
>   EditPackages=UnrealEd
>   EditPackages=GFxUIEditor
>   EditPackages=IpDrv
>   EditPackages=OnlineSubsystemPC
>   EditPackages=OnlineSubsystemGameSpy
>   EditPackages=OnlineSubsystemLive
>   EditPackages=OnlineSubsystemSteamworks

then add your own line pointing to a folder named what ever you want but make sure it has a folder in it named Classes and it has the uc files you wnat to compile in it

```
ModEditPackages=MyTestProject
```

if you used that line then you are tellign udk you have a folder named

MyTestProject

located in your development/src folder and you want it to compile everything in there

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Here are some info which might be useful to you.

First, both your .sln and your .ucproj files must be located in Development/src. Then, under visual studio, right-click your project (.ucproj file in the solution explorer) and open its properties.

You must set, under the General tab:

- Target Game: UnrealEngine 3 Mod
- UCC Path: ....\Binaries\Win32\UDK.exe
- Reference Source Path: ..\Src

Under the Build tab:

- check "Build debug scripts"

Under the Debug tab:

- Start Game Executable: ....\Binaries\Win32\UDK.exe
- Load map at startup: the name of your startup map, without path nor extension
- Start with the specified game type: put your GameInfo class used for your mod, ie. MyMod.MyGameInfo
- Disable startup movies can be checked to gain time at launch
- Enable unpublished mods must be checked.

In your command line, the parameter -vadebug specifies that the breakpoints will be enabled.

After that, you must be able to build your script from Visual, and launch your game by pressing F5.

Breakpoints should work but you can't put them on a variable declaration, you have to put them on a function call, an assignment or a condition statement.

Hope this will help.