# Debugging UDK games with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, unreal-development-kit

I want to debug a game which was built using the Unreal Development Kit (UDK). Is it possible to use Visual Studio to debug large UDK games? If not, are there any other options?

Comment: see also - [Debugging UDK using nFringe in Visual Studio 2005](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392523/debugging-udk-using-nfringe-in-visual-studio-2005)

Comment: A quick google-venture says "yes" to udk, curious here-  what does "large" mean, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Try nFringe, or one of these:

- http://forums.epicgames.com/threads/940192-UnrealScript-IDE-for-Sublime-Text-2-NEW-Debugger
- http://forums.epicgames.com/threads/749655-Unreal-Script-IDE-Editor-Debugger-Ini-Editor